# Keep maximum row in consecutive rows with specific value in column based on another column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df.

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'id_c':[1] * 4 + [2] * 3 + [3] * 4,
        'Run':[7,8,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,5], 
      'Date_diff':[4,12,0,0,2,2,10,1,1,3,3]})

id_c   Run   Date_diff

1    7      4
1    8      12
1    5      0
1    4      0
2    3      2
2    2      2
2    1      10
3    2      1
3    3      1
3    4      3
3    5      3
```

For each unique value of id_c , if Date_diff equals to 0 , 1 , 2 for two consecutive rows , I want to keep the row with the maximum value in Run.

I tried :

```
df.groupby(['id_c' , 'Date_diff'])['Run'].idxmax()]
```

But it also selects maximum values for values of Date_diff different than 0 , 1 , 2.

The desired output would be :

```
id_c Run   Date_diff
1    7      4
1    8      12
1    5      0
2    3      2
2    1      10
3    3      1
3    4      3
3    5      3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, compute a custom group and get the max index per group, then slice:

```
# get values not in 0/1/2
mask = ~df['Date_diff'].isin([0,1,2])
# group the consecutive 0/1/2 and get id of max Run
idx = df.groupby(['id_c', (mask|mask.shift()).cumsum()])['Run'].idxmax().values

# slice output with max ids
out = df.loc[idx]
```

output:

```
    id_c  Run  Date_diff
0      1    7          4
1      1    8         12
2      1    5          0
4      2    3          2
6      2    1         10
8      3    3          1
9      3    4          3
10     3    5          3
```

Comment: Done! Can you please explain why you added the shift() and cumsum()? I looked at the documentation but it's still unclear to me. Thanks!

Comment: @user38646 the shift is to ensure the last non match value in Date_diff is not included in the next group. This is a classical ways of generating groups in pandas, set a boolean array, cumsum to group the False/zeros together